# PL/SQL - Execute immediate loop using parameter and if/then statement

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql

Within a shell script I am using a pl/sql block to drop certain users using $USER parameter. If another parameter `${DROP_AB}` is Y then drop all users from the cursor. How do I drop all users except one specific user `${USER}AB` if the parameter passed is N? Please see below and help with suggestions:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT username FROM dba_users WHERE username LIKE '${USER}%';
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN c1
    IF ${DROP_AB}='Y' THEN
      LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' ||user_rec.username|| ' CASCADE';
    ELSIF ${DROP_AB}='N' THEN
      LOOP
        --DROP ALL USERS EXCEPT FOR USER '${USER}AB'
   END LOOP;
END;
END;
/
```

Comment: you cant directly take all users from dba_users and drop them, even if the user enters 'Y' or 'N', pls run the select statement for select username from dba_users , you will find a list of sys related schemas as well.
It would be a better idea to get the list of all the users to be dropped and then run the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code but somthing along the lines of the below should work, but as suggested in the comment above this will then error on the system schemas / users.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT username FROM dba_users WHERE username LIKE '${USER}%';
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN c1 loop
    IF ${DROP_AB}='Y' THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' ||user_rec.username|| ' CASCADE';
    ELSE
        IF user_rec.username != ${USER}AB THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' ||user_rec.username|| ' CASCADE';
        END IF;
    END IF;  
   END LOOP;
END;
END;
/
```

Comment: For the else condition.. will it drop all users like `${USER}%` except for `${USER}AB`?

Comment: The IF user_rec.username != ${USER}AB THEN around the drop statement should stop it dropping that user.